# How to handle lock in cache (ConcurrentHashMap) using java

Tags: java, multithreading, caching, concurrenthashmap, in-memory

I am designing a cache system using `concurrenthashmap` which is shared among multiple threads. It also has two methods, get and put. I am unable to handle one scenario. The scenario is, if multiple threads want to get data from the cache and the key is not available, then one thread will get data from the database and put it into thecache `(ConcurrentHashMap)`. The other threads will wait until `thread-1` sets data into the cache then other threads will read data from the cache. How will I achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like you need [`computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## `ConcurrentHashMap#computeIfAbsent`

As [commented by Wasserman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67449764/how-to-handle-lock-in-cache-concurrenthashmap-using-java/67452181#comment119219814_67449764), the `ConcurrentHashMap` class offers a [`computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#computeIfAbsent(K,java.util.function.Function)) method to do just what you want. The method works atomically to:

- See if the map has an entry for that key. If so, returns the value for that key.
- If no entry found, executors your specified lambda function to produce a value. That value is stored as a key-value entry in the map. And, that value is returned.

All that work happens atomically, meaning that your map operates in a thread-safe manner without you needing to add any further protection.

To quote the Javadoc:

> If the specified key is not already associated with a value, attempts to compute its value using the given mapping function and enters it into this map unless null. The entire method invocation is performed atomically.

Example code using a method-reference for your code to retrieve a value from the database:

```
map.computeIfAbsent( myKey , key -> repository::fetchValueForKey ) ;
```

… or use a method call:

```
map.computeIfAbsent( myKey , key -> myRepository.fetchValueForKey( key ) ) ;
```

### Example app

Here is a complete example app.

We use a map of tracking which day-of-week is assigned to which person’s name, mapping a `String` to a [`java.time.DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) enum object, a `Map< String , DayOfWeek >`.

We start with a map of two entries for `Alice` & `Bob`. Our goal is to find a third entry for `Carol`. If not found, add an entry for that key with a value of [`DayOfWeek.THURSDAY`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/DayOfWeek.html#THURSDAY).

We define a class `Repository` which we pretend is doing a call to a database to lookup the value assigned to key of `Carol`.

Our task to be executed is defined as a [`Callable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) that returns a `DayOfWeek` object. We submit our `Callable` object several times to an executor service. That service returns `Future` objects through which we can track success and retrieve our result (which we expect to be `DayOfWeek.THURSDAY` object).

To show results, we dump the `Map` to console, along with the result of each `Future`.

```java
package work.basil.demo.threadmark;

import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class MapApp
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        MapApp app = new MapApp();
        app.demo();
    }

    private void demo ( )
    {
        Map < String, DayOfWeek > inputs =
                Map.of(
                        "Alice" , DayOfWeek.MONDAY ,
                        "Bob" , DayOfWeek.TUESDAY
                );
        ConcurrentMap < String, DayOfWeek > map = new ConcurrentHashMap <>( inputs );
        System.out.println( "INFO - Before: map = " + map );

        Repository repository = new Repository();

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

        Callable < DayOfWeek > task = ( ) -> { return map.computeIfAbsent( "Carol" , ( String personNameKey ) -> {return repository.fetchDayOfWeekForPersonName( personNameKey ); } ); };
        List < Callable < DayOfWeek > > tasks = List.of( task , task , task , task , task );
        List < Future < DayOfWeek > > futures = List.of();
        try
        {
            futures = executorService.invokeAll( tasks );
        }
        catch ( InterruptedException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        executorService.shutdown();
        try { executorService.awaitTermination( 10 , TimeUnit.SECONDS ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }

        System.out.println( "INFO - After: map = " + map );
        futures.stream().forEach( dayOfWeekFuture -> {
            try
            {
                System.out.println( dayOfWeekFuture.get() );
            }
            catch ( InterruptedException e )
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch ( ExecutionException e )
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } );
    }

    class Repository
    {
        public DayOfWeek fetchDayOfWeekForPersonName ( final String personName )
        {
            return DayOfWeek.THURSDAY;
        }
    }
}
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/dHb26p).

```
INFO - Before: map = {Bob=TUESDAY, Alice=MONDAY}
INFO - After: map = {Bob=TUESDAY, Alice=MONDAY, Carol=THURSDAY}
THURSDAY
THURSDAY
THURSDAY
THURSDAY
THURSDAY
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ReadWriteLock` that is provided by `java.util.concurrent` package.

```java
ReadWriteLock readWriteLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
...
void write() {
  readWriteLock.writeLock().lock();
  try {
    // read from db and write to cache
  }
  finally {
    readWriteLock.writeLock().unlock();
  }
}

void read() {
  readWriteLock.readLock().lock();
  try {
    // read from cache or from the db
  }
  finally {
    readWriteLock.readLock().unlock();
  }
}
```